Creating HD maps for AD from laser scan data and other sources
Currently I am working with a project, where my goal is to real time map updates for AD through RGB-d video feed. The problem I am facing is with the creation of the base map which will be updated later. I have been researching techniques to build a HD map from laser scan data and fusing other sources like road networks. I haven't found a clear step by step method to do so yet. There's a lot of file formats, tools for different tasks which is very overwhelming for me.
I have this laser scan data of the region where I will be doing the experiments. Here is the metadata:
The laser scan data was downloaded from https://asiointi.maanmittauslaitos.fi/karttapaikka/tiedostopalvelu/laserkeilausaineisto_05?lang=en
Coordinate system    etrs-tm35fin
Scanning date    2023-06-12
Elevation precision (m)    0.1 m
Elevation system    N2000
Flight altitude (m)    1475 m
File format    LAZ
Updated    2023-10-12T05:50:00.276458Z
Map sheet number    R4412H4
Point cloud identifier    laser/automaattinen/2023/20230206_Swissphoto_Oulu_kesa/Harvennettu/R4412H4
Point density (points per m²)    0.5 pistetta/m2
Project(s)    20230206_Swissphoto_Oulu_kesa
Scanner    Riegl, VQ780IIS
Scanning timeframe    C
Year of scanning    2023

I have two sources from where I can get the roads and topography:
https://www.openstreetmap.org/
other one is from the same website I got the laser scan from, but this data is a bit different:
https://www.maanmittauslaitos.fi/en/maps-and-spatial-data/datasets-and-interfaces/product-descriptions/topographic-map-series-raster
I am confusing how do I create the HD map from this data! What other data I need to build a good HD map?
Please   provide me with some guidance.
